# How to call a method from another method within the same object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm just getting started in OO javascript so please bear with me.

This works:

```
var myObj = {
     foo : function() {
            alert('hello');
            this.bar();
     },
     bar: function() {
            alert('world');
     }
}
```

However if I do some other stuff after the hello alert in the "foo" method then the meaning of "this" changes from the object to whatever I last selected so using `this.bar()` doesn't execute the other method in the class.

So I tried to cache "this" in a variable like so:

```
var myObj = {
     publicVars: {
            theObj : this
     },
     foo : function() {
            alert('hello');
            publicVars.theObj.bar();
     },
     bar: function() {
            alert('world');
     }
}
```

But that didn't work either. So what is the solution?

### EDIT

Here is my actual code:

```
var formObj = {

     validate : function(theForm) {
            $('input, textarea', theForm).each(function() {
                 var valueLength = $(this).val().length;
                 if (valueLength === 0) {
                        $(this).addClass('invalid');
                        this.listenForInput($(this)); // <!------- this isn't working
                 }
            });
     },
     listenForInput : function(theField) {
//          theField.keyup(function() {
//               if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
//                      theField.removeClass('invalid');
//               }
//          });
            alert('I work!!!!');
     }

} // end obj
```

Comment: What is that " other stuff " because this shouldn't change inside that object.

Comment: What is the "other stuff" you are talking about? If you are creating a callback, then yes `this` will refer to `window` (most likely). In this case you just have to create a reference to `this` inside `foo` first.

Comment: I posted my actual code in the edit. Please take a look.

Comment: With regard to your updated code, you seem to want `this` to refer to your `formObj`, and the DOM element at the same time. That's just not going to happen. `this.listenForInput($(this));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you have to keep a reference inside the function:

```
validate: function(theForm) {
    var self = this;
    $('input, textarea', theForm).each(function() {
        var valueLength = $(this).val().length;
        if (valueLength === 0) {
           $(this).addClass('invalid');
           self.listenForInput($(this));
        }
    });
},
```

You are passing a function to `each`. Inside this callback, `this` refers to the DOM element. That's why you pass it to jQuery (`$(this)`) to be able to call jQuery methods on that element. It cannot refer to `formObj` too!

---

What `this` refers to is determined by *how* a function is called and each function has its own `this` (the [Mozilla documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) describes `this` in more detail).

If you call `validate` with `formObj.validate()`, then `this` refers to `formObj`.

The jQuery [documentation for `each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) states:

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

Answer (score 4):

Am I missing something, or can you not just reference the object by name, like this:

```
var myObj = {
    foo: function() {
        alert('hello');
        myObj.bar();
    },
    bar: function() {
        alert('world');
    }
}

myObj.foo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/kaXYj/

Comment: yup works, didn't know you could reference an object just by it's name. All the tutorials use "this" keyword, the people above said the meaning of "this" should never change. But it did for me, so not sure what's going on there but yes this works, thanks.

Comment: Although this is a fix, I would suggest accepting @Felix Kling's answer, which I think is better suited to this situation. I had not fully understood the context of your question at the time of writing as you had not added your actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A function's *this* keyword is set by the call, it can't change during function execution.

Calling `obj.foo()` sets *foo*'s *this* to *obj* so calling *this.bar* calls *obj.bar*. However, if you call *foo* some other way, e.g.:

```
var a = obj.foo;
a();
```

then its *this* will may be *obj* (in the above case it will be *window* or *undefined* in strict mode) so you get a different *bar* or an error if the *this* object doesn't have a *bar* property.